# Laravel eloquent 5.3 Eager/Lazy loading related models with multiple limit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I'm leveraging Laravel's eloquent by Lazy/Eager Loading and have come across an interesting issue.

**Description:**

- An account has many groups, each with a priority number
- All groups Contain Items in them

**The issue:**

- I need to manually set a limit to the number of returned items of each group
- The difference here is that the limit number changes based on each groups priority level

So, for example, the eloquent "select" statement would get all three groups but limit the number of items returned in group 1 to just 3 items, group 2 to just 8 items, group 3 to 17 items.

**What I've tried to do:**

- Code in Controller to get records

  ```
  return Account::with([
  'group_list.item'
  ])->where('group_id', $my->group_id)
  ->orderBy('group_priority_num', 'ASC')
  ->take(3) <----Gets three groups
  ->get(['group_priority_num','group_title','group_id']);
  ```
- Group Model

  ```
   public function group_list() {

   // Example
   $this->number = [4 , 7, 15];


   return $this->group()->limit($this->number)->groupBy('user_group_id_fk');
   }
  ```

This only returns 1 record or none at all, so I'm currently confused about how to approach this correctly. Can someone lend me some guidance on this?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated, Thank you in advance.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eager loading is implemented via a second query using `WHERE foreign_key_column IN (list of primary model IDs)`. With such a query it is impossible to set a limit on per model basis unless there's some other condition that the results can be further filtered by.

You have 3 options:

- Let Eloquent eager load everything and filter the results in PHP according to your needs.
- Perform the eager loading your self by fetching only the primary model followed by separate queries for each model's relationships with their respective limits.
- Add a flag column to your groups table that would let you mark the rows that should be returned for each group.

Comment: There may be a 4th option as well, where I would make a pull request that would add in this type of functionality... however developing it would take more time than I have to spare currently. What you say makes sense though. 
Thank you for the response! 
Cheers mate!